# (perl, html) Change two form values with one submit button?

Tags: html, forms, perl

The application I am working on uses the variables $mode and $action for navigation. for example:

```
$mode = param('mode');
$action = param('action');

if ($mode eq 'mode1') {
  if ($action eq 'savedata') {
    &savedata();
  } elsif ($action eq 'showform') {
    &showform(); 
  }
}
```

Typically, I will only need to change the action param, which I can do with the buttons.

```
$button1 = "<button type='submit' id='saveBenefit' style=\"$button_style\" name='action' class='button1' value='save'>Save</>";
$button2 = "<button type='submit' id='processBenefit' style=\"$button_style\" name='action' class='button1' value='process'>Save And Process</>";
```

But:

When I click button1, I want the 'mode' param to stay as benefit, and the 'action' param to be 'save'.
When I click button2, I want the mode param to be 'transaction' and the 'action param to be 'process'.

How can I change more than one form value (both action and mode) based on the button that is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Can't without using some client-side scripting. But that would be silly. Just include enough information in the button's value. You don't even need to make any change to your form:

```
$mode = 'transaction' if $action eq 'process';
```

Comment: I have no problem with using client-side scripting, but I haven't been able to get it to work in any way. 

Where would I put that line? Assigning $mode in any way other than with the initial param seems fairly messy (there are about 30 different modes) .

Comment: You'd create an `onclick` handler that sets the `mode` input and returns a true value.

Comment: Can't really say more. You've provided no information that allows for a deeper answer, but I do indeed get the sense that your approach is messy.

Comment: My form has a hidden 'mode' field, which I gave the id=benmode. I then used **"document.getElementById('benmode').innerHTML= transaction"** with an onlcick function but it didn't work.



But it didn't work. param('mode') is still benefit